# change of variables in integral - how do limits change?

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

If I have this integral:

$$\int_0^{\sigma_0}xR^2dR$$

and I know that $x=\frac{R}
{\sigma_0}$

and I substitute:

$$\int x (x\sigma_0)^2 dx= \int x^3 \sigma_0^2 dx$$

what are the new integration limits?

Comment: To put formulas into display format (= on their own line, big integral signs etc.) simply use double dollar signs round them. (That's all I did in my edit, other than editing the fraction.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits of integration are given as $R= 0$ and $R= \sigma_0$.  You change variables from R to $x= \frac{R}{\sigma_0}$.  When $R= 0$, then, $x= \frac{0}{\sigma_0}= 0$.  When $R= \sigma_0$, $x= \frac{\sigma_0}{\sigma_0}= 1$

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the integration limits according to the substitution. The new extremes turn out to be $0$ and $1$.